# Clearing the selection in a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, exec

I have a form with webbrowser control ,where i am coping all the TEXT(not html) data to clipboard

For this the code snippet is :-

```
webBrowser2.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
webBrowser2.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
```

I have written the above code under webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted .

The problem is that the webpage in webbrowserControl appears with selection. I want to clear that selection after copy operation.

Is there a way to do this or a command such as

```
 webBrowser2.Document.ExecCommand("ClearSelection", false, null);  //This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import the Microsoft.mshtml library (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`), you can use the `selection` property of the web-browser's `Document`:

```cs
using mshtml;

...

IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser2.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

IHTMLSelectionObject selection = htmlDocument.selection;

if (selection != null) {
    selection.clear();
}
```

Otherwise, you could always `Navigate` to a script URI:

```cs
webBrowser2.Navigate("javascript:document.selection&&document.selection.clear();");
```

**Edit:** Changed it to use `Navigate`, instead of `InvokeScript`.

Comment: second method is not working on my machine and web browser goes blank.

Comment: no it did not. The web browser only loads master page  content and rest everything is blank

Comment: htmlDocument.execCommand("UNSELECT", false, Type.Missing); worked for me. I found this on  http://www.ssicom.org/js/x277333.htm .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to unselect the selection then use:

```
htmlDocument.ExecCommand("Unselect", false, Type.Missing);
```

But if you want to remove (hide) a word selected:

```
IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser2.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
IHTMLSelectionObject selection = htmlDocument.selection;

if (selection != null) {
    selection.clear();
}
```

Comment: At least in my C# project "Unselect" works. 
myDoc.execCommand("Unselect", false, null);

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the Refresh method of the browser control to do the same thing. (i.e. `webBrowser2.Refresh()`)

Comment: That was just what I needed. :)

Comment: A refresh is IMHO something different than clearing a selection. Even if it clears a selection.